# Explain forEach Arguments

Tags: javascript, foreach

Version 1:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
numbers.forEach(function(x) {
  sum += x;
});
console.log(sum);
 //15
```

Version 2:

```
var numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], sum = 0;
numbers.forEach(function(asdf) {
  sum += asdf;
});
console.log(sum);
 //15
```

Why is the function inside forEach can take any argument? As you can see it's the same if I put "asdf" or "x". I really want to know the concept behind this.

Thanks You!

Comment: Index of argument matters not the name used. First argument id the current element in the iteration and second argument is the index.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach you can get full information here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing specific about `forEach` here. JavaScript never cares what arguments are named (at least, not beyond requiring that they are valid identifier names), only what position they are in in the argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, forEach when called on an array will assign the value (1, 2, 3, 4 , 5) in your case and assign it to the variable (of any name). It doesn't care whether it's `x` or `asdf`

Answer (score -1):

The concept is that javascript passing a single item to callback function as it iterate through entire given dataset. The name of the param doesn't matter (as long as it's valid by javascipt variable naming rules). The param name is for you to use, value is same.